# ASP.net: need thead for sorting gridview with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

i have a gridview in asp.net/vb and it is bound to a list - so there's no standard sorting available.

I've found this jQuery plugin for sorting tables: http://tablesorter.com/

The plugin requires `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.

The problem is, that my gridview only renders the `<tbody>`.

I've already tried

```
    DataList.UseAccessibleHeader = True
    DataList.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

but this changes nothing.

My gridview markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="grid" ID="DataList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" ClientIDMode ="Static">
 <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SomeHeaderText" DataField="SomeDataField" />  
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SomeHeaderText" DataField="SomeDataField" DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SomeHeaderText" DataField="SomeDataField" DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" />                                         
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>
       <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <asp:Label Text="xxx" runat="server" ID="xxx" />
       </asp:Panel>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2" HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="./myImage.png" runat="server" Height="20px" />
     </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What can i do?

Comment: "it is bound to a list - so there's no standard sorting available."  you can do sorting on gridview, for that nly MS Paid Lacs of $$ to employee to invent :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to use the paging feature of the gridview control so i suggest that you move to the "Repeater" as it will give you the power to format the table header section and footer and it will give you the power of rendering the table exactly as you want it to be rendered.